# getting force close error on back key

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem when I press the back key to leave game at this web site. I get a forced error message on back key. I used the destroy code I learned from my first question. Didn't change anything. Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.limejs.com/static/roundball/index.html");

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
    // to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    myWebView.destroy();
}
```

}

```
Here is the Logcat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.roundball.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:33)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1256)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2078)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent
(PhoneWindow.java:1771)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2563)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2538)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1870)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)`enter code here`
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I have used this code before to load web sites, it is just particular to this game?
```

Comment: Show the log, that's how we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

i would remove the return true; right after the finish();

It would help if you had some adb logs to show the exact error you are getting.

You can also check to see if myWebView is not null. I am thinking that might be null as well.

Comment: I removed the return true; Same results. I have used this code to access web sites and back key out with no problem. This site which is a game. Is doing something strange that I'm not aware of. I have enter the Logcat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your log says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.roundball.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:33)

Which means there is a null reference in the code inside the onKeyDown method at the moment of execution. You only use 2 references there, but since its unlikely that you receive a null KeyEvent (it comes from the Android Runtime and documentation says implicitly that you always receive a valid reference when onKeyDown is called), it has to be the reference to your webview. So check if myWebView != null before calling myWebView methods, like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if(myWebView != null) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        android.util.Log.w("MyActivity", "myWebView is null!!");
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
    // to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

From that code I can't tell what is causing you to have a null reference to the webview, but It might tell you where to look next for the problem if you expect your webview reference to be not null.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the code given below.. basically.. i updated your call to finish() to MainActivity.this.finish() , where MainActivity is your activity! So, **you will have to change MainActivity to whatever name you gave.**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
    // to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I added your line to the MainActivity file with the same results. I'm not sure what's going on other than a fatal exception error. The thing that is strange is that the MainActivity goes to a web site and exits without a problem. Strange???

Comment: I did very similar to what you want to have... by the way, why do you need  myWebView.destroy();?

Comment: you may just need super.onDestroy(); by itself.. and not deleting your myWebView.destroy()...

Answer (score 0):

```
//replace for this   

 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
                if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    return MainActivity.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                }else{
                    myWebView.destroy();
                    MainActivity.finish();
                    return false;
                }
    }
```